# Toit - How can I connect to `localhost` using `http.Client`?

Tags: toit

I am trying to test Toit on an ESP32 on my local network. I have a `fastapi` app running on my laptop and I'm trying to run a GET request.

I am using the `http` package:

```
$ toit pkg install github.com/toitlang/pkg-http
```

My Code `main.py`:

```
import http
import net
import encoding.json

URL ::= "localhost:8000"
PATH ::= "/"

main:
  network := net.open
  client := http.Client network
  // The `get` method automatically closes the connection when
  // the response has been fully read.
  response := client.get URL PATH
  data := json.decode_stream response.body

  print data
```

But I am getting the error: `Connection refused`

```
$ toit run --device <UUID> main.toit
2022-05-30T20:47:00.111752Z: <process initiated>
2022-05-30T20:47:00.384733Z: <stack trace>
EXCEPTION error.
Connection refused
  0: TcpSocket.connect         system/modules/tcp.toit:149:40
  1: TcpSocket.connect         system/modules/tcp.toit:139:12
  2: WifiNetworkInterface.tcp_connect system/components/wifi.toit:101:7
  3: NetworkInterfaceResource.tcp_connect system/components/network.toit:95:26
  4: register_network.<lambda> system/components/network.toit:26:23
  5: KernelBroker.register_descriptor_procedure.<lambda> system/kernel/rpc.toit:44:14
  6: RpcRequest_.process.<block> <sdk>/rpc/broker.toit:98:26
  7: RpcRequest_.process       <sdk>/rpc/broker.toit:95:3
  8: RpcRequestQueue_.ensure_processing_task_.<lambda>.<block>.<block> <sdk>/rpc/broker.toit:214:20
  9: RpcRequestQueue_.ensure_processing_task_.<lambda>.<block> <sdk>/rpc/broker.toit:209:9
 10: RpcRequestQueue_.ensure_processing_task_.<lambda> <sdk>/rpc/broker.toit:204:56



2022-05-30T20:47:00.518790Z: <process terminated - exit code: 1>
```

I get the same result whether I use `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000`.

---

I am able to hit the endpoint on my laptop with a simple cURL command, so the endpoint is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toit run` command executes the application on the ESP32. As such, the `localhost` then refers to the device itself and not your machine.

You can either try to run the Toit program locally on your machine (using the open-source version of Toit: https://github.com/toitlang/toit/releases), or you can change the `localhost` to the IP address of your machine.

How you get the IP address of your local machine depends on your operating system. On my Linux machine I would just type `ip address`.